# Keeping an open connection in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to create a module, which keeps an open connection to Flickr API and keeps on receiving new recent photos.
I've tried the 'agentkeepalive' node module, but cloudfront seems to block the requests. This is what my current module code looks like, obviously, the fetch now only runs once:

Server side

```
require('dotenv').config()
var Flickr = require('flickr-sdk')
var flickr = new Flickr(process.env.FLICKR_API_KEY)

var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
  )
  next()
})

app.get('/fetch', function(req, res) {
  (() =>
    flickr.photos
      .getRecent()
      .then(result => {
        return res.send(result.body.photos.photo)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error: ', err)
      }))()
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

Client side

```
import './App.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      fetchClicked: false,
      photos: [],
    }
  }

  onFetchClick = () => {
    this.state.fetchClicked
      ? this.setState({ fetchClicked: false })
      : this.setState({ fetchClicked: true }, () => {
          axios.get('http://localhost:5000/fetch').then(response => {
            this.setState({
              photos: response.data,
            })
          })
        })
  }

  render() {
    const { fetchClicked } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="App p-5 bg-secondary">
        <h1>Flickr Streamer </h1>
        {fetchClicked ? (
          <button className="btn btn-info" disabled>
            Streaming...
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button className="btn btn-info " onClick={() => this.onFetchClick()}>
            Start the stream!
          </button>
        )}

        <div>{this.state.dataReceived}</div>
        <table className="table table-dark mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Photo</th>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {this.state.photos.map(item => {
              return (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td>
                    <img
                      src={`https://farm${item.farm}.staticflickr.com/${item.server}/${item.id}_${item.secret}.jpg`}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td scope="row" className="w-50">
                    {item.title || 'No name'}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Polling is usually the way to do this kind of thing. This is how I would do it:

```
fetch = () => axios.get('http://localhost:5000/fetch')
  .then(({data}) => this.setState({ photos:data })

onFetchClick = () => 
    this.setState({ fetchClicked: !this.state.fetchClicked }),
    () => this.fetch()
      .then(() => setInterval(() => this.fetch(), 15 * 1000))
```

This doesn't deal with the user clicking the button more than once, but if that callback only executes if the state changed, or you disable the button when it is clicked, that would be handled for you by that. Otherwise, you'd have to handle it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can this be achieved without polling?

Comment: No, Flickr are not going to dedicated an open connection to your app. That way lies a very quick death for their server.